# Why this javascript doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript to hide an element input field depending on the value in a hidden field

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$('#ccType').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'maestro')
        $('#cvv').closest('.name').hide(); 
    else
        $('#cvv').closest('.name').show();
});

    </script>
```

But this is not hiding the element I want

here is html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>| todo</title>
        <meta name="description" content="app, web app, responsive, admin dashboard, admin, flat, flat ui, ui kit, off screen nav">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-select.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css" cache="false">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fuelux/fuelux.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugin.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cards.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.njj.com/inpage/js/tokenex-client.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function getApp() {
                var thisURL = window.location.href;
                var thisSession = new Array();
                thisSession = thisURL.split("?"); //This grabs all URL parameters
                var session = thisSession[1];
                thisSession = session.split("="); //This gets the session ID from URL
                if (thisSession[0] == 'merchant_id') {
                    var thisApp = new Array();
                    thisApp = thisSession[1].split("&");
                    var webapi_MerchantID = thisApp[0];
                    thisApp = thisSession[2].split("&");
                    var passkey = thisApp[0];
                    thisApp = thisSession[3].split("&");
                    var amt = thisApp[0];
                    thisApp = thisSession[4].split("&");
                    var email = thisApp[0];
                    thisApp = thisSession[5].split("&");
                    var mobileNo = thisApp[0];
                    thisApp = thisSession[6].split("&");
                    var orderID = thisApp[0];
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            thisSession = result.split("&");
                            if (thisSession[0] != 0) {
                                var amount = parseFloat(thisSession[0]).toFixed(2);
                                var x = document.getElementsByName('amount');
                                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                    x[i].value = amount;
                                }
                            }
                            var x = document.getElementsByName('merchant_id');
                            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                x[i].value = thisSession[1];
                            }
                            var x = document.getElementsByName('customerReferenceNo');
                            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                x[i].value = thisSession[2];
                            }
                            var x = document.getElementsByName('email');
                            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                x[i].value = thisSession[3];
                            }
                            var x = document.getElementsByName('mobileNo');
                            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                x[i].value = thisSession[4];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "initiateConnctPay.php?merchant_id=" + webapi_MerchantID + "&passkey=" + passkey + "&amount=" + amt + "&email=" + email + "&mobileNo=" + mobileNo + "&orderID=" + orderID, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                } else if (thisSession[0] == 'button_id') {
                    var button_id = thisSession[1];
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            thisSession = result.split("&");

                            if (thisSession[0] != 0) {
                                var amount = parseFloat(thisSession[0]).toFixed(2);
                                var x = document.getElementsByName('amount');
                                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                    x[i].value = amount;
                                }
                            }
                            var x = document.getElementsByName('merchant_id');
                            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                x[i].value = thisSession[1];
                            }
                            var x = document.getElementsByName('customerReferenceNo');
                            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                x[i].value = thisSession[2];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "initiateButtonPay.php?button_id=" + button_id, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                } else if (thisSession[0] == 'inv_no') {
                    var inv_no = thisSession[1];
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            thisSession = result.split("&");

                            if (thisSession[0] != 0) {
                                var amount = parseFloat(thisSession[0]).toFixed(2);
                                var x = document.getElementsByName('amount');
                                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                    x[i].value = amount;
                                }
                            }
                            var x = document.getElementsByName('merchant_id');
                            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                x[i].value = thisSession[1];
                            }
                            var x = document.getElementsByName('customerReferenceNo');
                            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                x[i].value = thisSession[2];
                            }
                            var x = document.getElementsByName('email');
                            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                x[i].value = thisSession[3];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "initiateInvoicePay.php?inv_no=" + inv_no, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                } else if (thisSession[0] == 'resrvCode') {

                } else if (thisSession[0] == 'collctCode') {

                } else {
                    alert("You are unauthorized to use this application!");
                    document.getElementById("btn_process").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("nb_process").disabled = true;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section id="content" class="m-t-lg wrapper-md animated fadeInDown">
            <div class="row m-n">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 m-t-lg">
                    <section class="panel">
                        <header class="panel-heading bg-light">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                                <li class="active" id="cc"><a style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500;" href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Credit Card</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="db"><a style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500;" href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Debit Card</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500;" href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Internet Banking</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </header>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                                    <form method="post" action="./TokenProcess.php" id="cardpayment">
                                        <input id="txtEncryptionKey" name="txtEncryptionKey" class="tokenex_encryptionkey" <input id="txtEncryptionKey" name="txtEncryptionKey" class="tokenex_encryptionkey" type="hidden" value="MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8gGPMwBRPuVyJReZGIkW
H/+Bf5pnpDN1bSR2cLYLXVT8CaSnTw74qeboSnktgYCi1D9R3Bj2fYzTIwGGZb8K
inLdxwbqZmHwrE9cFhCaHbG/fcURzl2Hnw/inqyMy
+JB6djTq2/BdzMAhWTh3cDWq9Xu+gEkb/QCd0n1yYIdKuDISlk/AfHdWe34IvzhV
yQIDAQAB
 " />
                                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:0px">
                                            <input type='hidden' id='ccType' name='ccType' />
                                            <ul class="cards">
                                                <li class="visa">Visa</li>
                                                <li class="visa_electron">Visa Electron</li>
                                                <li class="mastercard">MasterCard</li>
                                                <li class="maestro">Maestro</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Card Number</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="ccnumber" id="ccnumber" placeholder="411111111111111" class="form-control tokenex_data">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">CVV</label>
                                            <input type="password" id="cvv" name="cvv" placeholder="123" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" style="display:inline;">Expiry</label>
                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                                <div class="inline pull-left m-r">
                                                    <div style="height:30px">
                                                        <select class="selectpicker" id="expiry_month" name="expiry_month">
                                                            <option selected>Select Month</option>
                                                            <option value="01">January</option>
                                                            <option value="02">February</option>
                                                            <option value="03">March</option>
                                                            <option value="04">April</option>
                                                            <option value="05">May</option>
                                                            <option value="06">June</option>
                                                            <option value="07">July</option>
                                                            <option value="08">August</option>
                                                            <option value="09">September</option>
                                                            <option value="10">October</option>
                                                            <option value="11">November</option>
                                                            <option value="12">December</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="inline pull-left m-r">
                                                    <div style="height:30px">
                                                        <select class="selectpicker" id="expiry_year" name="expiry_year">
                                                            <option selected>Select Year</option>
                                                            <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                                            <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                                            <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                                            <option value="2020">2020</option>
                                                            <option value="2021">2021</option>
                                                            <option value="2022">2022</option>
                                                            <option value="2023">2023</option>
                                                            <option value="2024">2024</option>
                                                            <option value="2025">2025</option>
                                                            <option value="2026">2026</option>
                                                            <option value="2027">2027</option>
                                                            <option value="2028">2028</option>
                                                            <option value="2029">2029</option>
                                                            <option value="2030">2030</option>
                                                            <option value="2031">2031</option>
                                                            <option value="2032">2032</option>
                                                            <option value="2033">2033</option>
                                                            <option value="2034">2034</option>
                                                            <option value="2035">2035</option>
                                                            <option value="2036">2036</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Amount</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="100.00" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Name on card</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="name_on_card" id="name_on_card" placeholder="Enter name as on card" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Mobile Number</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="mobileNo" id="mobileNo" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="customerReferenceNo">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="selectedRadioValue" class="selectedRadioValue">
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="margin-left:35%">
                                            <button type="submit" id="btn_process" name="btn_process" class="btn btn-info tokenex_submit">Pay Now</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="line line-dashed"></div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div style="float:left;margin-right:7%;">
                                                <img src="http://www.fethr.com/webapp/images/lock.png">
                                            </div>
                                            <p style="display:inline;"><small>Your card details are secured via 128 bit encryption</small>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="messages"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <!-- App -->
        <!-- Fuelux -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
                    style: 'btn btn-white btn-sm'
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.toke.com/inpage/js/tokenex-client.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('button').on('click', function() {
                    if ($("#cc").hasClass("active")) {
                        $('.selectedRadioValue').val('radio1');
                    } else if ($("#db").hasClass("active")) {
                        $('.selectedRadioValue').val('radio2');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $('#ccType').change(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == 'maestro') $('#cvv').closest('.name').hide();
                else $('#cvv').closest('.name').show();
            });
        </script>
        <script src="js/cardvalidation.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please update your question and only provide the code that is absolutely necessary.

Comment: i just gave the full html to check if some other script is conflicting this

Comment: How are you filling `#cctype`? it is a hidden input field.

Comment: hidden field is filled y=using another javascript

Comment: Can you show that JS where you fill that field with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a class of "name" thus the closest cannot find a match... Try this instead:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $('#ccType').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 'maestro') 
                $('#cvv').hide();
            else 
                $('#cvv').show();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I have used the same script in another html which is almost similar to this and it worked when.change is used since,if the hidden field value changes,then the script should work

Comment: Cool okay, give me a sec.. ill go look at this properly on my desktop.. loo laptops are useless for this

Comment: You're right the .change does work... nearly found the issue :)

Comment: :) thanks..please find it out..i have been on this for a long time and cant find,why not working

Comment: and 1 UP for that effort :)

Comment: What are you wanting to hide with your closest statement? I do not see any class="name" but your closest statement says .name

Comment: oh..i see it was a class in the previous html i used.Should I remove it and try?

Comment: I just want to hide the cvv field

Comment: Its working ,I removed it :)I didnt noticed that..Forget to change that.Thanks